# Use Python to display content from URL

Tags: python

I am brand new to Python coding, and getting stuck with a particular task.

I have the following URL: https://freeman7.zendesk.com/api/v2/views/313117127/count.json

I would like to use Python to display something like the following (this is the content that that URL displays when you open it in a web browser):

```
{
"view_count": {
"url":     "https://freeman7.zendesk.com/api/v2/views/313117127/count.json",
"view_id": 313117127,
"value":   2,
"pretty":  "2",
"fresh":   true
}
}
```

I've tried all sorts of things after searching the Internet for a couple of hours, but can't seem to find anything that works. Here is an example of something I've tried:

```
import urllib.request, json
with urllib.request.urlopen("url") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data)
```

And here is the error I get for that:

URLError: urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Anyone have any idea what's going on here, and/or have a recommendation on how I could successfully complete this task? I would appreciate any insight!

Thanks,
Stephen

Comment: What is the authentication method for this API?

Comment: You must authenticate: https://freeman7.zendesk.com/access/unauthenticated

Comment: I would generally recommend [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to do that. It's interface is more intuitive and it is easier to keep an authenticated session than with `urllib`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Could someone help me understand what syntax I would use to add authentication info?

Comment: Approach: Use a `requests` `Session` object to post proper credentials on the login page, then use the same `Session` object to make the API call. You wil have to read some doumentation ;)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import json

import requests

url = 'https://freeman7.zendesk.com/api/v2/views/313117127/count.json'
response = requests.get(url)
response_json = response.json()
print(json.dumps(response_json, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Results:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "There is no help desk configured at this address. This means that the address is available and that you can claim it at http://www.zendesk.com/signup",
        "title": "No help desk at freeman7.zendesk.com"
    }
}
```

If I had access to the actual content it would be better, but this will work for all JSON responses from a URL.

Also, for viewing JSON content in a browser, this Chrome extension is clutch:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa